# Aria2 max-connection not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, download, aria2

I installed aria2 (1.18.1) in my ubuntu.
but the problem is it can not increase download connection.

```
aria2c -x 10 http://mirror.sg.leaseweb.net/speedtest/100mb.bin
[#fe34b4 2.1MiB/95MiB(2%) CN:4 DL:233KiB ETA:6m49s]
```

by default it only download from 4 connection not 10 (as i given).
i even try with another sites, but default 4 connection carried out while downloading

---

Solved:-

There are multiple options that influence the behavior:

--split -s Maximum number of concurrent splits (connections) per download. Defaults to 5, so unless you changed it, you will get max 5 connections for a single download no matter what -x.

--min-split-size -k A split should only be initiated when the split would be bigger than this. Defaults to 20M, meaning that when you download a 100M file, the time the download is split some data is already retrieved which means less slightly less than 100MB is remaining, meaning 4 splits (5 splits would create splits slightly less than 20MB).

There you have it. Please check out the manual for more information on the various options.

```
$ aria2c -k 1M -s 10 -x 10 http://mirror.sg.leaseweb.net/speedtest/100mb.bin
[#1325f1 7.4MiB/95MiB(7%) CN:10 DL:1.2MiB ETA:1m8s]
```

Comment: Please remove "Solved" from your title and question. You can post it as a proper answer and then mark it as "Accepted".